# Running external program within java produces different results from terminal command

Tags: java, curl

Hey I'm trying to run a command within `java`:

```
String curlCommand=String.format("curl --max-time %d --socks5 %s -A \"%s\"  -i %s",maxWait,proxy ,getAgent(), myurl);
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(curlCommand);
```

For some reason executing this line would result in `cookies` to be denied.

however, when I run the curl program from terminal I have no problem and everything works as it should be

here is the result  if I run the program `Java`

```
Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2015 19:20:38 GMT
X-Li-Pop: prod-lva1
X-LI-UUID: 8C548z0TyBMwY002tCoAAA==
Set-Cookie: denial-reason-code=3,2,8; Max-Age=5
Set-Cookie: denial-client-ip=xxxxxxx; Max-Age=5
Content-Length: 1852
Content-Type: text/html
```

here is the result if I run exact command using  `curl` in `terminal`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Play
X-SSR-Engine-Init: <xxxxxxx>
X-FS-UUID: 0e69d33f4913c813b05f1aefb42a0000
X-Page-Speed: 1
Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2015 19:21:27 GMT
Content-Length: 31113
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Li-Fabric: prod-lva1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID="ajax:4773794645302404176"; Path=/; Domain=<xxxxxx>; HTTPOnly
Set-Cookie: bcookie="v=2&da2801ec-e7e2-4b04-8244-401d6ac0e7c3"; domain=xxxxx; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 03-Mar-2017 06:58:59 GMT
Set-Cookie: bscookie="v=1&2015030319212713ed4940-eb5d-4860-8c30-2eec4819157aAQHMGWOb0Fiv_feTewpb6Rw3TGGAGQ_Q"; domain=<xxxxxx>; Path=/; Secure; Expires=Fri, 03-Mar-2017 06:58:59 GMT; HttpOnly
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Connection: keep-alive
X-Li-Pop: prod-lva1
X-LI-UUID: DmnTP0kTyBOwXxrvtCoAAA==
Set-Cookie: lidc="b=VB97:g=149:u=1:i=1425410487:t=1425496887:s=AQHAOhdkFxryw00Wo64LkfjsYb8Q1hqZ"; Expires=Wed, 04 Mar 2015 19:21:27 GMT; domain=<xxxxx>; Path=/
```

So My question is why should it be different at all, am I missing something out here?

Comment: Are you running 32-bit JVM trying to launch a 64-bit executable or vice versa?  If so, try running a 32-bit JVM with 32-bit executable or a 64-bit JVM with a 64-bit executable.

Comment: How do you get the output of the runtime exec? There is a stream for 'stdout' and a stream for 'stderr'. Check both streams and post it here.

Comment: @chris the streams is from stdout are fine. I tried to reduce the noise. some of the output is with the question. the problem is the when I use java the cookies are not set. I haven't tried to print out stderr. thx for mentioning that.

Comment: @Palamino I'm using default ubuntu packages. and the java version is 64bits

Answer (score 0):

Alright I finally solved it.

the reason is `Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();`

it should not be used. as it just messes up with the parameters (eventhough the print out of the command looks fine, it just didn't send the right command to the OS)  instead I should have used `ProcessBuilder` `class`. it worked like a charm.